# Maximum Principle for Poisson’s Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

I understand how to prove the maximum principle for $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, but how does this extend to a maximum principle for the equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=f$?

I believe this is called Poisson’s equation. Here $u$ is given by a prescribed function $f$ in a bounded domain $D$.

I just don’t see how the same proof generalises (the one about perturbing $u$ to force a positive Laplacian, eg considering $v(x,y)= u(x,y) + \epsilon (x^2 + y^2)$).

Thanks for help.